# fullcalendar google integration returns a 403 error?

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm experiencing a 403 forbidden error when trying to retrieve a google public calendar feed using fullcalendar. I notice the problem also exists on fullcalendar's demo is this a change from google?

http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.2.0/demos/gcal.html

Comment: Google calendar API v2 was deprecated on Nov 17, 2014.  It appears this included the "public/full" URI that FullCalendar uses.  I am also looking for a solution to this, it seems that FullCalendar needs to be updated to use v3 of the API.  Here's the deprecation announcement:  https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v2/developers_guide_dotnet?hl=de-DE

Comment: It appears that the developer has already added v3 support.  See my answer below.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. I have followed it all through and can get the event data returned in my browser so just waiting for the fullcalendar update.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Google has deprecated and shut down Calendar API v1 and v2.  The "public/full" URL is no longer available.

FullCalendar is being updated to support API v3.  Once released you will be able to use a v3 style URL.  First create an API key in Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com).  Then use the following for the URL in FullCalendar, substituting your calendar ID and API Key:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{YOUR_CALENDAR_ID}/events?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

The developer commented in the issue that the changes should be released tomorrow (Nov 19th).  You can find more details and track the progress in this issue:

[https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=1526&colspec=ID
 Type Status Milestone Summary Stars](https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=1526&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Milestone%20Summary%20Stars)

Comment: fullCalendar has now been updated to support API v3. (Both versions: v1.6.6 and v2.2.2). Downloads here: https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar/releases

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the [Google Calendar API JSON Output](https://developers.google.com/gdata/samples/cal_sample). FullCalendar converts feeds like

```
http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/usa__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com/public/basic
```

into

```
http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/usa__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com/public/full?alt=json-in-script&callback=?
```

in gcal.js on line 49

```
url: sourceOptions.url.replace(/\/basic$/, '/full') + '?alt=json-in-script&callback=?',
```

There does not seem to be any indication that the specs have changed. So, I assume that there is a problem somewhere in Google.

**EDIT**

[More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26978312/fullcalendar-js-there-was-an-error-while-fetching-events/26982452#26982452)

Comment: Thanks Butch. It's due to Google depreciating v3 of the calendar API.

Answer (score 0):

Adam updated the plugin to support the new Google Calendar API.

See the documentation here: 
http://fullcalendar.io/docs/google_calendar/